# Parent when addning new module with IntelliJ Idea Kotlin and Gradle

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, module, multi-module

as C# developer, I'm trying to understand how modules works in Java/Kotlin. When I create a new Project in IntelliJ based on Kotlin and add a new module, there is a option Parent.  If I choose None I get a message during the build

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.3.72']
> Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version
```

and if I remove the version

```
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

If I do the same, but when adding a new module I choose instead of None a Parent project, everything works. So my question is what is a difference between adding a Parent when creating new module. And when should i use one over another.

Comment: `> Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version` From the error it looks like this project is included in other's project build. Are you sure the root (or any other Gradle module you have in this project) does not have `include` directive (in `settings.gradle` file) for this project where you are getting this error?

Comment: Hi, yes there is include directive in settings.gradle. But if i remove it, how can i reference my new module. Adding  implementation("modulename:moduleversion") is not working.

Comment: `if i remove it, how can i reference my new module` then to reference it you first need to publish it into your [local repository](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-local-repository) on the computer. But you will not be able to reference it directly to a module's sources. So, unless there is a reason I would use `include` and referent the module directly. Then you can configure plugins, dependencies, tasks (if needed) for modules via `subprojects` `allprojects` blocks: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:subproject_configuration